# Adding space after dot but not in URL

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have a text that has sentences that may not have space after a dot like:

> See also vadding.Constructions on this term abound.

How can I add a space after a dot that is not before the domain name? The text may have URLs like:

> See also vadding.Constructions on this term abound. http://example.com/foo/bar

Comment: is url always in last? does url always start with `http(s)`?

Comment: @rock321987 no, it may be inside a text in any place.

Comment: I suggest you to get the URL from string, remove it, than add spaces on the string, and at the finish add the address again to string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match and capture an URL and just match all other dots to replace with a dot+space:

```js
var re = /((?:https?|ftps?):\/\/\S+)|\.(?!\s)/g; 
var str = 'See also vadding.Constructions on this term abound.\nSee also vadding.Constructions on this term abound. http://example.com/foo/bar';
var result = str.replace(re, function(m, g1) {
 return g1 ? g1 : ". ";
});
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + result + "</pre>";
```

The URL regex - `(?:https?|ftps?):\/\/\S+` - matches `http` or `https` or `ftp`, `ftps`, then `://` and 1+ non-whitespaces (`\S+`). It is one of the basic ones, you can use a more complex one that you can easily find on SO. E.g. see [*What is a good regular expression to match a URL?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url).

**The approach in more detail**:

The `((?:https?|ftps?):\/\/\S+)|\.(?!\s)` regex has 2 alternatives: the URL matching part (described above), or (`|`) the dot matching part (`\.(?!\s)`).

**NOTE that `(?!\s)` is a negative lookahead that allows matching a dot that is NOT followed with a whitespace.**

When we run `string.replace()` we can specify an anonymous callback function as the second argument and pass the match and group arguments to it. So, here, we have 1 match value (`m`) and 1 capture group value `g1` (the URL). If the URL was matched, `g1` is not null. `return g1 ? g1 : ". ";` means we do not modify the group 1 if it was matched, and if it was not, we matched a standalone dot, thus, we replace with with `.` .

Comment: I re-read the question and adjusted the answer to only add spaces after dots that are not followed with a space: `var re = /((?:https?|ftps?):\/\/\S+)|\.(?!\s)/g;`.  Please review and let me know which option to keep.

Comment: This replace all dots by dot and space but not in url, I need to have only one  space after dot.

Comment: Do you want to say you need to only add a space after 1 dot that is immediately followed with a URL? Then see Shafizadeh's answer.

Comment: No, in your solution dot before the url have 2 spaces (because it already have a space) and it need to have one space only.

Comment: @jcubic: My update (see the first comment) is exactly what you need. **I precised the answer**.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern:

```
/\.(?! )((?:ftp|http)[^ ]+)?/g
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gM0iV4/4)

Comment: It need to replace first dot.

Comment: I guess this is what OP needs after the comment to my answer. Just add an option for `https` and remove the `?`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `RegExp` `/(\.)(?!=[a-z]{2}\/|[a-z]{3}\/|\s+|$)/g` to match `.` character if not followed by two or three lowercase letters or space character

```
"See also vadding.Constructions on this term abound. http://example.com/foo/bar"
.replace(/(\.)(?!=[a-z]{2}\/|[a-z]{3}\/|\s+|$)/g, "$1 ")
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew _"Why do you think it should work?"_ ? Not certain follow?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Given string at OP, should match only first `.` character. Added `$` to not match `.` if end of input; e.g., at first string at OP

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes? `RegExp` at post should return expected results https://jsfiddle.net/b27yr1g1/ . Though currently tld's do exist tld's where `.` could be followed by more than two or three characters

Comment: Never you mind, the question is unclear. See, even OP decided to answer himself.

Answer (score 0):

Using idea from @MarcelKohls

```js
var text = "See also vadding.Constructions on this term abound. http://example.com/foo/bar";
var url_re = /(\bhttps?:\/\/(?:(?:(?!&[^;]+;)|(?=&amp;))[^\s"'<>\]\[)])+\b)/gi;
text = text.split(url_re).map(function(text) {
  if (text.match(url_re)) {
    return text;
  } else {
    return text.replace(/\.([^ ])/g, '. $1');
  }
}).join('');
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + text + '</pre>';
```

Comment: You can do that by pure regex `/\.(?! )((?:ftp|http)[^ ]+)?/g` !! *(without that callback and condition)*

Comment: My answer provides exactly the same behavior but is more compact. Please review it. I deleted the first regex I suggested and left only the version with a negative lookahead after a standalone dot matching alternative.